# need assistance h2 tags, nested links, image hyperlink

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

So I am answering a question for homework.

This is the question....

Create a list of a few different foods in the following categories:  Sandwiches,  Drinks, Desserts. Create these categories using an `h2` tag.

- Under each of these three items, have another list (i.e. a nested list) that lists at least three items for each.  For example, under sandwiches you might have: Hamburger, Hot Dog, Panini.   The outer list should be ordered. The inner list should be unordered.
- For one of the categories, have each item in the inner list hyperlinked to an image. So if under ‘Drinks’ you have ‘Mimosa’ as one option, when the user clicks on Mimosa, your page should display an image of a mimosa. Have the image display in a new tab.  Note: To hyperlink to an image, you only need to type the filename of the image as the value to the ‘href’ attribute. You should not write ‘http’ or anything else. Simply type the name of the file.

As of right now this is my coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> Restaurants </title>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
    <h1>Sandwiches</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="tumblr_lyoqzfcKU51qflpc1o1_500.jpg">Italian Beef</a></li>
            <li><a href="gyro.jpg">Gyro sandwich</li>
            <li><a href="picxgAGER.jpg">Lamb Kabob sandwich</li>
        </ul>
    <h2>Drinks</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Dr-Pepper.png">Dr. Pepper</li>
            <li><a href="large-vs-3.jpg">Hennessy</li>
            <li><a href="BL_Miller_GD_Square_KV_300dpi_A2.jpg">Miller Genuine Draft</li>
        </ul>
    <h3>Dessert</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="larger.jpg">Ice Cream Donuts</li>
            <li><a href="Chocolate-Milkshake.png">Chocalate Milkshake</li>
            <li><a href="whollyfrijolesthumb.png">Fried Ice Cream</li>
        </ul>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the link it doesn't go to the image I want. And the words drink and dessert are connected to a hyperlink but I don't want them too. Can anyone take a look at my code and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your question resolved? If so, please click the checkmark beside the best answer to close the question. If not, please tell us what else requires attention and we will do our best to rally 'round. If you have additional questions, please close this question and ask a new question - new questions receive hundreds of immediate views. Revised questions are reviewed only by the few people who happen to look at the updated question. It is always better *(faster response, more answers)* to ask lots of discreet questions rather than one question with several parts.

Answer (score 1):

Drinks and Dessert are hyperlinked because you are missing the closing tag at the end of the previous `</a><li>` (end of Lamb Kabob and Miller Genuine Draft.

The images are correctly written, but the code expects the images to be in the same folder as the web page itself. What folder are the images really in?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added the close tags. And moved the pictures into the same folder.